# Android game countdown timer

Tags: android, timer, countdown

I'm working on a game where I need a countdown timer.

I need to be able to pause the timer, resume the countdown and to add some time to current countdown state.

I've looked at `CountdownTimer` class and its methods, but it seems like it doesn't have the required features.

I need advice - which component is best for this case?

How to use it?

What are the possible problems?

`Thread`? `AsyncTask`? `Timer`?

Does anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Thread can be used, but its easier to implement your features using CountdownTimer wrapper class:

```
    static class MyCountdownTimer {

    long mCurrentMilisLeft;
    long mInterval;
    CountdownTimerWrapper mCountdownTimer;

    class CountdownTimerWrapper extends CountDownTimer{
        public CountdownTimerWrapper(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval) {
            super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mCurrentMilisLeft = millisUntilFinished;
        }

    }

    public MyCountdownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {          
        set(millisInFuture,countDownInterval);
    }

    public void pause(){
        mCountdownTimer.cancel();
    }

    public void resume(){
        mCountdownTimer = new CountdownTimerWrapper(mCurrentMilisLeft, mInterval);
        mCountdownTimer.start();
    }

    public void start(){
        mCountdownTimer.start();
    }

    public void set(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval){
        mInterval = countDownInterval;
        mCurrentMilisLeft = millisInFuture;         
        mCountdownTimer = new CountdownTimerWrapper(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

}
```